# leaflet/JSONobject. Marker onclick show only last record

Tags: onclick, leaflet, markers, json

that my code

```
 <div id='map'></div>
 <div id="info"></div>

 [...] 

var markers1 = new L.MarkerClusterGroup( { showCoverageOnHover: true } );

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "db.php",
    success: function (result) {
        var JSONobject = JSON.parse(result);
        var jnCount = JSONobject.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < jnCount; i++) {
            var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(JSONobject[i]["lat"],JSONobject[i]["lng"]),{ icon: myIcon1 });

            var id = JSONobject[i]["id"];
            var list = "<dl>"

                    + "<dt><b>CITTA':</b> " + JSONobject[i]["citta_"] + "</dt>";

            marker.on('click', function()
 { {document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = list;} }); 


            markers1.addLayer(marker);
        }
        map.addLayer(markers1);

    }

});
```

Marker onclick shows only the last record! I think problem is in loop but I don't understand how fix it. Any idea?

Thanks

Nicola

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call the click function, it looks back at the `list` variable that is inside the function, meaning it looks at the last value of the `list` variable.  The problem and potential solution is detailed in the Stack answer: [Javascript closure inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

You can try to fix it with the above information, or you can modify the [Leaflet Choropleth tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) to be based on points.  It's currently based on polygons, but it shouldn't be a big problem to migrate it to points and an `onClick` function.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I try to fix with your suggests ;)